# Expected covered area as integral of the probability of being covered?

Tags: probability, geometry

If I have a disk $\mathcal{D}$, where each point is "covered" randomly with probability given by $$P(x \text{ is covered}) = p(x)$$ so that each point of the disk has a position-dependent probability of being covered, I understand I can write that the expected value of the total covered area

$$\mathbb{E}(\text{total covered area}) = \int_{\mathcal{D}}P(x \text{ is covered})  \mathrm{d}x$$

but I am not sure how this relates to the definition of expected value. It seems relatively clear but I'm not sure how to prove it. Does it follow straightforwardly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{P}_n=\big\{\mathcal{B}_i,x_i\big\}_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of tagged partition of $\mathcal{D}$ such that $\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\mu(\mathcal{B}_i)\longrightarrow 0$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$. Naturally, we'll $$\text{cover all } \mathcal{B}_i \iff x_i \text{ gets covered}$$ Define $\mathbb{X}_i=1$ if $\mathcal{B}_i$ gets covered and $\mathbb{X}_i=0$ otherwise. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(\mathcal{B}_i)\mathbb{X}_i$ is the total covered area whose expected value is $$\mathbb{E}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(\mathcal{B}_i)\mathbb{X}_i\bigg)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(\mathcal{B_i})\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{X}_i)=\sum_{i=1}^np(x_i)\mu(\mathcal{B}_i)\longrightarrow \int_{\mathcal{D}}p(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ as $n \longrightarrow \infty$

Comment: Ok I see the $\mu$ is becomes the $\mathrm{d}x$, and the $p$ is the probability of being covered.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact known as **Robbins' theorem**.

See Section 2 of Garwood, [**The variance of the overlap of geometrical figures with reference to a bombing problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/biomet/34.1-2.1), Biometrika 34, 1-17 (1947).

or

**[Theorem 8.24](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xiPaZKAq_mUC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=robbins%20theorem%20measure&source=bl&ots=PM8Tz0jged&sig=ACfU3U0yFL9ZaZ-ENT89Xi6F9XGdPJzMnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM1v6FyZD0AhXSTcAKHb_2BAgQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=robbins%20theorem%20measure&f=false)** of I. Molchanov **[*Theory of Random Sets*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xiPaZKAq_mUC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=robbins%20theorem%20measure&source=bl&ots=PM8Tz0jged&sig=ACfU3U0yFL9ZaZ-ENT89Xi6F9XGdPJzMnQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM1v6FyZD0AhXSTcAKHb_2BAgQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=robbins%20theorem%20measure&f=false)** (Springer, 2006).